# In Angular 2: set function in directive not fired

Tags: angular, binding, angular2-directives

I don't understand why the alert() in the setter of my directive below is not fired every time the value of the input element I am applying this directive to changes.
It only fires the first time, when I refreshe the page.

I thought that since the value property was bound, the setter would be fired every time I strike a key in the input. It doesn't.
Also I tried to change the value of the input programatically with a button. It doesn't fire the setter either.

Could anyone be so gentle to telle me what I am wrong?

My app.agcomponent.ts is the following:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'ag-component'
  , template:
  `
<input type="text" id="myinput" value="Mickey"  ag-directive>
<button (click)="onButtonValueClick($event)">Value</button>
`
})

export class AGComponent {    
    onButtonValueClick(event) {
        document.getElementById("myinput").value ="Pluto"; 
    }

}
```

And my app.agdirective.ts is the following:

```
import { Directive } from '@angular/core';
import { ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[ag-directive]'
    , inputs: ['value: value']
})
export class AGDirective {
    set value(pValue) {
            alert(pValue);
    }    
}
```

Comment: change to use ngOnChanges instead of setter

Comment: Hey Bo Chen. I tried what you said. Unfortunately the result it exactly the same: ngOnChanges is only fired the first time, when the page loads.

Comment: you need to change your input value : [value]="something here you want to pass to ag-directive"

Comment: I'm sorry. I tried everythnig over the last 3 days, but it wouldn't work.
Could you provide me with a small but full example?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing @Input() in your declaration.

```
export class AGDirective {
    @Input()
      set value(pValue) {
            alert(pValue);
      }    
}
```